# Migrating from vSphere 5.5 to another datacenter 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi

We are planning to migrate the production VMs from one of our datacenters, based on ESXi 5.5 hosts, to a new datacenter with 6.5 environment. Datacenters are located in different places.

So our production consists of near 150 VMs. I've set the network connection and tried VMware converter to transfer a couple of test VMs, but the migration performance wasn't well. I can't set up the replication due to limited access to the network between the datacenters. We do not have anyone to perform that, cause the guy who maintained the datacenter left the company, and I need to do it myself.

Are there another options how to migrate? Are there also some restrictions in migrating from 5.5 to 6.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don’t worry about powering off the VMs, you can copy them over SSH. It's exactly what I did to migrate my production a while ago and the migration was succusfully completed. Also there was a good article about production migration:

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/virtual-workload-migration-with-vmware.

Regarding VMs – there are no restrictions in moving to 6.5 – here’s the compatibility link:

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-65/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-64D4B1C9-CD5D-4C68-8B50-585F6A87EBA0.html

Comment: Ok, thx. Migrating over SSH then. We don't need the VMs to work continuously so there's a good option.